# PHP, как соединить многомерные массивы, у которых есть одинаковый id

Tags: php, массивы

Тоесть, у меня есть такой массив.

```html
  array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "OS"
    ["text"]=>
    string(7) "Android"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "OS"
    ["text"]=>
    string(3) "ios"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Гарантия"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "2 года"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Гарантия"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "2 года"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Переплата"
    ["text"]=>
    string(6) "Нет"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Переплата"
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "Да"
  }
}
```

У меня получалось, но мой код это велосипед.
А хотел сделать такой вид: (чтобы одинаковые значения не дублировались еще)

```html
  array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "OS"
    ["text"]=>
      [0]=> string(7) "Android"
      [1]=> string(7) "ios"
  }

  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Гарантия"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "2 года"
  }

  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["name"]=>
    string(18) "Переплата"
    ["text"]=>
      [0]=> string(7) "Да"
      [1]=> string(7) "Нет"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идеального решения как по мне не найти, всё равно выйдет что-то странное из-за того что вы хотите получить на выходе такую структуру, попробовал сделать группировку с минимальным кодом, получилось следующее:

```
$array = [
    [
        'attribute_id' => 27,
        'name' => 'OS',
        'text' => 'Android'
    ],
    [
        'attribute_id' => 27,
        'name' => 'OS',
        'text' => 'ios'
    ],
    [
        'attribute_id' => 28,
        'name' => 'Гарантия',
        'text' => '2 года'
    ]
];

function combineAttributes($input) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($input as $value) {
        // Если нет в массиве значения - просто добавляем и идём дальше.
        if (!array_key_exists($value['attribute_id'], $result)) {
            $result[$value['attribute_id']] = $value;
            continue;
        }

        // Если значение есть - пробуем добавить ещё одно значение в поле text.
        $item = &$result[$value['attribute_id']];

        if (is_array($item['text'])) {
            $item['text'][] = $value['text'];
        } else {
            $item['text'] = [
                $item['text'],
                $value['text']
            ];
        }
    }

    // array_values можно убрать если вам не принципиально какие ключи будут у массива.
    return array_values($result);
}

var_dump(combineAttributes($array));
```

На выходе получается то что в и хотели:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    int(27)
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "OS"
    ["text"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Android"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "ios"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    int(28)
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Гарантия"
    ["text"]=>
    string(10) "2 года"
  }
}
```

Comment: @ЯнМинибаев в смысле нету?

Comment: Ты просто гений))) Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Да спасибо, но дубликация, почему-то у меня осталось)

```
 [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "27"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "OS"
    ["text"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Android"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "ios"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["attribute_id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "Гарантия"
    ["text"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2 года"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "2 года"
    }
  }
```

Исправил так)))

```
function combineAttributes($input) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($input as $value) {
            // Если нет в массиве значения - просто добавляем и идём дальше.
            if (!array_key_exists($value['attribute_id'], $result)) {
                    $result[$value['attribute_id']] = $value;
                    continue;
            }

            // Если значение есть - пробуем добавить ещё одно значение в поле text.
            $item = &$result[$value['attribute_id']];

            if (is_array($item['text'])) {
                    $item['text'][] = $value['text'];
            } else {
                if($item['text'] != $value['text']) {
                    $item['text'] = [
                            $item['text'],
                            $value['text']
                    ];
                }
            }
    }

    // array_values можно убрать если вам не принципиально какие ключи будут у массива.
    return array_values($result);
```

}
Хотя стойте наверное это из за знака & или меня штормит